# Como escribir un párrafo dentro de un solo <option> de un <select multiple>

Tags: css, html5, select, html-select, multiselect

Quiero que dentro del valor `<option>` de un `<select>` entre un párrafo de tres líneas con el nombre de un club de fans, el dueño y la cantidad de miembros. Intente usar `<br>` pero el `<select>` no lo toma en cuenta y escribe todo el texto en la misma línea. Anexo el código del `<select>` acepto cualquier sugerencia en html o en css.

```
<select class="multiple" multiple name="clubes">
   <option value="1">Biblioteca Stark<br>Dueño Actual: Tony Stark<br>Miembros: 15</option>
   <option value="2">El Calabozo del Androide<br>Dueño Actual: Jeff Albertson<br>Miembros: 7</option>
   <option value="3">La Atalaya Comics<br>Dueño Actual: Jefferson Gutierritos<br>Miembros: 5</option>
   <option value="4">La Mansión Wayne<br>Dueño Actual: Bruce Wayne<br>Miembros: 8</option>
   <option value="5">ORDEN 66 Internacional<br>Dueño Actual: Darth Vader<br>Miembros: 5</option>
   <option value="6">Orden Jedi Mundial<br>Dueño Actual: Joda<br>Miembros: 9</option>
   <option value="7">Renegados de la Fuerza<br>Dueño Actual: Asoka<br>Miembros: 10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No es bien visto colocar *urgente* o *lo mas pronto posible*, la ayuda dependerá de que en la comunidad haya quienes tengan tiempo y el conocimiento para ayudarte ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n Espero te sirva, puedes hacerlo usando css

Answer (score 1):

Ya que necesitas solo 3 líneas, una posibilidad seria utilizar pseudo-elementos before y after donde:

• el `before` representa la primera línea,

• el texto del option es la segunda línea y

• el `after` la tercera línea.

Cada elemento option tiene un atributo data-before y otro data-after que serán utilizados para definir el `content` de los pseudo-elementos.

Por favor observa que los pseudo-elementos tienen `display:block` para crear una nueve línea de texto.

```css
select{height:140px}
option{padding: 1em;}
option::before{content: attr(data-before);
       display:block;
}
option::after{content: attr(data-after);
       display:block;
}
```

```html
<select class="multiple" multiple name="clubes">
  <option value="1" data-before="Biblioteca Stark" data-after="Miembros: 15k">Dueño Actual: Tony Stark</option> 
  <option value="2" data-before="Biblioteca Bark" data-after="Miembros: 18k">Dueño Actual: Jeff Albertson</option>
  <option value="3" data-before="Biblioteca Clark" data-after="Miembros: 10k">Dueño Actual: Reff Bertson</option> 
</select>
```